# JQuery spinner is skipping 0 on first click

Tags: jquery

I'm using a JQuery spinner on an input field. But the first time i click on the + button, the spinner skips 0 and goes straight to 0.5.

I could of course fix this by adding a value = "0" to the input, but the idea is that the input starts blank.

Here's my code:

**HTML**:

```
<input id="test">
```

**JQuery**:

```
$("#test").spinner({
step: 0.5,
icons: {
    up: "ui-icon-plus",
    down: "ui-icon-minus"
},
spin: function (event, ui) {

    if (ui.value > 20) {
        $(this).spinner("value", 0);
        return false;
    } else if (ui.value < 0) {
        $(this).spinner("value", 20);
        return false;
    }        
    if (ui.value > 3 && ui.value !== 0) {
        $(this).spinner("option", "step", "1");
    } else {
        $(this).spinner("option", "step", "0.5");
    }
}
```

});

I also made a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5cmt2so7/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle herre: http://jsfiddle.net/5cmt2so7/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont understand why you dont want to set initial value for input but you can do sth. like that

```
$(".test").spinner({
    step: 0.5,
    icons: {
        up: "ui-icon-plus",
        down: "ui-icon-minus"
    },
    count:0,
    spin: function (event, ui) {

        if($(this).spinner("option", "count") < 1 ){
            $(this).spinner("value", 0);
            $(this).spinner("option", "count",$(this).spinner("option", "count") + 1 );
            return false;
        }            


        if (ui.value > 20) {
            $(this).spinner("value", 0);
            return false;
        } else if (ui.value < 0) {
            $(this).spinner("value", 20);
            return false;
        }        
        if (ui.value > 3 && ui.value !== 0) {
            $(this).spinner("option", "step", "1");
        } else {
            $(this).spinner("option", "step", "0.5");
        }
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cmt2so7/11/)

Comment: Ok, that works for the first input field. But i should have explained that it has to work on 20 input fields that all have the same class. I updated my fiddle to clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/5cmt2so7/10/

Comment: i see, so heres another way to solve it to meet your requirements ;-)